# App crashes when webViews try to load in a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller

So the premise of my app is that it has multiple tabs and each tabViewController has a webView property that loads up a different webpage.

I'm not sure what exactly is wrong, and why it crashes.

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x6a7c5b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key webView.'`

The way I structured the app was I made separate ViewController classes for each tab. I included IBOutlets to the WebViews and linked them to webViews I included in the storyboard. I also set the CustomClass to the ViewController class.

Here is an example of my code (it's pretty much synonymous across the ViewControllers):

**AmericaViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AmericaViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

**AmericaViewController.m**

```
#import "AmericaViewController.h"
@implementation AmericaViewController
@synthesize webView = _webView;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // allow user to pinch-zoom page
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    self.webView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

    //load webView
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://baylornotes.org/articles/America"]]];   
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception, one of your UIViewController has no property webView.
Maybe one of your classes is not well written, or you forgot to set the right class in a xib...

Comment: I checked though, and all the webViews were fine. At least, they were all connected. By the way, what exactly is a xib? Is it similar to a StoryBoard?

Comment: A xib is a file where you describe one screen whereas a storyboard allow to describe multiple screens and interactions between them.